# When a SQLAlchemy concurrent updates the same record what is wrong?

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

My project (flask+sqlalchemy) deployed by uWSGI (4 workers) and mysql (with InnoDB).

These are my Models:

```
class Cards(db.Model):
    id             =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    no             =db.Column(db.String(11),index=True, unique = True,nullable=False)
    balance        =db.Column(db.Numeric(12,2),nullable=False,default=0)


class trans_details(db.Model):
    id             =db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    from_card_id   =db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cards.id'),nullable=False)
    to_card_id     =db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cards.id'),nullable=False)
    amount         =db.Column(db.Numeric(12,2),nullable=False)

    from_card_balance=db.Column(db.Numeric(12,2),nullable=False)
    to_card_balance  =db.Column(db.Numeric(12,2),nullable=False

    timestamp      =db.Column(db.Numeric(17,7),default=time.time,nullable=False)#时间戳

    from_card      =db.relationship('Cards',foreign_keys=[from_card_id],
                    backref=db.backref('out_details',lazy='dynamic'))
    to_card        =db.relationship('Cards',foreign_keys=[to_card_id],
                    backref=db.backref('in_details',lazy='dynamic'))
```

And my code is something like this:

```
@contextmanager
def trans():
    try:
        yield
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        db.session.rollback()

def transfer(from_card,to_card,amount):
    with trans():
        from_card.balance=Cards.balance-amount
        to_card.balance=Cards.balance+amount

        db.session.add(from_card)
        db.session.add(to_card)
        db.session.flush()

        if from_card.balance<0:
            raise Exception('xxx')

        details=trans_details(from_card=from_card,
                          to_card=to_card,
                          amount=amount,
                          from_card_balance=from_card.balance,
                          to_card_balance=to_card.balance)
        db.session.add(details)
        db.session.flush()

def batch_transfer(rule):
    with trans():
        #parse the rule and call transfer function time after time
```

But sometimes I do not get the expected results, e.g:

```
select * from trans_details order by `timestamp` desc;

|from_card |to_card |amount |from_card_balance       |to_card_balance |timestamp
A          C        100     1000(This Should be 950) xxx              1413257244.5339300(2014-10-14 11:27:24)
A          B        50      1050                     150              1413257244.4818400(2014-10-14 11:27:24)
B          A        100     100                      1100             xxx
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.Is my problem,My code is as follows:

```
from_card=Cards.query.with_for_update().filter(xxx)
to_card=Cards.query.with_for_update().filter(xxx)
#call a function here,but in the function have a commit operation so..
transfer(from_card,to_card,amount)
```

Comment: I know that it is probably too late for you but just a comment on this solution since other people might stumble upon it: This could lead to a deadlock. Suppose that two transactions are executed concurrently. One from account A to B and the other from account B to A. The first transaction might now lock account A and the second transaction might lock account B.
To circumvent this you would need to use just one query that returns both Cards instead of two separate queries. And even then I'm not sure if MySQL guarantees freedom from deadlocks.